# Maven Jetty plugin: how to exclude from scan freemarker templates

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-plugin

I'm using the Maven Jetty plug-in in a Spring MVC project with a Freemarker view engine.
As suggested I put all my ftl templates under:

```
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ftl
```

Now, every time I make a change to an ftl file, Jetty restarts because of the autoscan feature.
I want to keep the autoscan and restart feature, but I don't want it to acto on ftl template files.

I read about the plug-in configuration and configured it like this:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <scanTargetPatterns>
        <scanTargetPattern>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.ftl</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </scanTargetPattern>
    </scanTargetPatterns>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
</configuration>
```

But it does not seem to work.
Every time I save an ftl Jetty restarts.